# try / catch not working for PDO within a class

Tags: php, try-catch

I have created a class.  One of the class methods (**public function pdoPrepare($pdo, $sqlStmt)**) is intended to standardize prepare statements (while doing logging, cleanup, et cetera).  For the most part it works quite well, but when there is an error in the SQL statement, I would like the calling routine to receive the error.  My attempt to accomplish this looks like this:

```
            ...
            $finalSQL = $left . $mid . $right ;
            }
        try {
            $prepared = $pdo->prepare($finalSQL) ; // Since this might fail, DO THIS BEFORE setting the $this->latest.... values.
            $this->latestPdoPrepareSQL = $sql ;
            $this->latestPreparedPDO = $prepared ;
            $this->latestPdoPreparePDO = $pdo ;
            }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->writeLogLine( [ "Problem with this SQL: %s" , $finalSQL ] ) ;
            throw($e) ; // Pass the problem back to the caller - ain't my fault we got here! :)
            }
        return $prepared ;
        }
```

However, the 'try' in this case does not seem to pass this exception to the associated 'catch' block.  Instead, the error is presented in place:

[image: Error presented to statement within try block]

Note that I am not trying to understand why I get this error, per se.  Instead, I am trying to understand why the error is not caught by the try{} block.

Comment: It is caught. Then it's thrown again by `throw($e)`

Comment: The throw() should throw it to the caller, not back to the try block.

Comment: What makes you think it isn't? Since the caller doesn't have a `try`, you get the default handler that makes it a fatal error.

Comment: In fact, the caller does have a try/catch block. (Why do you assume otherwise?)  To answer "what makes me think so?" - it's clearly stopped in error on that particular statement.

Comment: Which line is line 809?

Comment: I assumed otherwise because it's consistent with the result you're seeing.

Comment: Are you inside a namespace and not using a `use` statement? You might be missing the exception because you didn't anchor it as `\Exception` so it's assuming something like `\My\App\Exception`.

Comment: @Barmar, line 809 is the one that has an 8 and a 0 and a 9 to its left, in that order.

Comment: You mean the line that isn't shown in the screenshot, smart-aleck? Are you getting the log message from `$this->writeLogLine()`?

Comment: Please post a [mre]. I can only guess what the caller does.